A single value for column 'ReleaseGuidelineId' in table 'Query1' cannot be determined
Testfield = 
IF (
    'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId] = 1 && 'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo] = 2,
    "Up to 2",
    IF (
        'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId] = 1 && 'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo] = 3,
        "Up to 3",
        IF (
            'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId] = 2 && 'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo] = 3,
            "Up to 3",
            IF (
                'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId] = 3 && 'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo] = 2,
                "Down to 2",
                BLANK()
            )
        )
    )
)

The datatypes for both fields are Whole number but I keep getting this error when I shouldnt.
The values in both these columns are just either 1,2 or 3.
Error I get: A single value for column 'ReleaseGuidelineId' in table 'Query1' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

This below code will resolve the Error, but not sure this will serve your purpose or not.
Testfield = 
IF (
    'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId] = 1 
        && 'Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo] = 2,
    "Up to 2",
    IF (
        min('Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId]) = 1 
            && min('Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo]) = 3,
        "Up to 3",
        IF (
            min('Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId]) = 2 
                && min('Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo]) = 3,
            "Up to 3",
            IF (
                min('Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineId]) = 3 
                    && min('Query1'[ReleaseGuidelineIdOverriddenTo]) = 2,
                "Down to 2",
                BLANK()
            )
        )
    )
)

